# Floating floor tile (Snapstone). Can unlevel be fixed?

Tags: flooring, tile

[image: Unlevel area]

My friend and I put in this floor two years ago.  It is Snapstone, snap together, floating floor, tile that is grouted after installed.

Prior to install, he used floor leveler in the hall area to come up level with kitchen area, where a door jamb exists. All seemed ok originally but I had a feeling that this door area would be an issue.

Here are my 3 OFF THE WALL, LOW COST IDEA/remedies: Scrape out the grout, then...

1. Spray loctite expanding foam underneath,then regrout.
2. Pour leveling compound to seep through underneath, then regrout.
3. Just try to regrout?

I have no more of these tiles left.  This was a small budget project and I'm trying to keep it that way.

PS - Other than this, I LOVE this floor and product.

Comment: Sorry.. The floor shifts slightly (up/down) when walking directly on it.  So the tiles right there are uneven which has made the grout come unsealed (correct word?).

Comment: Please edit your post to add this clarifying information. Don't make your volunteer helpers dig for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that there's a depression or hump in the floor that you'd like to eliminate or reduce. The only right way is to disassemble the floor and prepare the subfloor properly. If you do it carefully you probably will be able to reuse the tiles.

Problems with your ideas:

1. Foam will compress and degrade over time. Also, it's *extremely* sticky and difficult to remove. Massive mess even if you manage to get it under the tiles.
2. Levelers will not "seep" through the cracks in any appreciable quantity, and certainly not enough to give your tiles the full support they require. Also, mess.
3. I'm not sure how this resolves the issue as I've assumed it.

Comment: Yes, it is a hump in the floor, where the door jamb was.  We used leveler but possibly not enough for this area.  I know all my ideas basically suck..LOL. I'm trying to avoid taking up tiles because this is the ONLY spot I have issues in a 12'x10' kitchen passing into a 13'x5' hallway area.

Comment: I wonder if taking out those three or four tiles and separating the rooms again would be an option.